# Is MySQL handling null values correctly when count(distinct col1, col2, col3)

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, multiple-columns

I was having trouble determining a possible unique key in a poorly defined table.  The table had 5000 rows.  I selected distinct on the fields I thought might be a unique key.

```
select count(distinct col1, col2)
from tab1;
```

The result was 4980 records.  Then I checked the 20 records and found that the values for col2 where null, but adding col3 should give me uniqueness.

```
select count(distinct col1, col2, col3)
from tab1;
```

The result was still 4980.  What the?  So I changed the query to this.

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(*)
from tab1
group by col1, col2, col3
having count(*) > 1;
```

With this I got zero rows, so col1, col2, and col3 are unique. So what was wrong with the first three column query?  I tried this.

```
select count(distinct col1, coalesce(col2, ''), col3)
from tab1;
```

This returned 5000 records.

It is likely that the multiple fields are being concatenated together in one field in the engine, and concatenating col1, NULL, col3 is resulting in NULL and that is why it is acting this way.  But, the result seems to break the NULL standards that MySQL seems to want to follow.  Is this a MySQL bug?

Comment: The [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) wording is a little vague, but seems to suggest COUNT(DISTINCT a, b, c) ignores any (a,b,c,) where a, b, or c are null.

Comment: @Uueerdo actually it says that specifically: [Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

Comment: @Nick like I said, vague; that can (and probably should) be interpreted as "returns count of the number of rows with different non-null... excluding rows with null expr values altogether." The current wording leaves it a little ambiguous how it treats rows with some null values; ex: (a, null, b) has different non-null values than (a, null, c); but is not counted at all.

Comment: I agree with Uueerdo.  It's a little vague.  But that wasn't my point.  I would expect the second and third query above to act the same.  Even if documented it acts inconsistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) specifically says that `COUNT(DISTINCT expr [,expr...])`

> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

which is the behaviour you are seeing.